# How can I reduce the amount of children I use in my jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, children

I feel like I have to use way too many `.children()` in some of my jQuery functions.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="goal-small-container">
  <div class="goal-content">
    <div class="goal-row">
      <span class="goal-actions">
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$('.goal-small-container').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('.goal-content').children('.goal-row').children('.goal-actions').css({visibility: "visible"});
}, function () {
  $(this).children('.goal-content').children('.goal-row').children('.goal-actions').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

**Is there a better way?** How can I reduce the amount of children I use in my jQuery functions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
.find('.goal-content .goal-row .goal-action').whatever()
```

or more simply:

```
.find('.goal-action').whatever()
```

Comment: This is not what I was expecting.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - party pooper

Comment: meder - The MJ was just creepy! ;o)

Comment: For those late to the party, Michael Jackson is apparently unrelated to children.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring If it generated page-views and more people learned, it was constructive.

Comment: @Josh Smith - People can still see the image if they view the edits.

Comment: @Gert - Yeah, it was (sadly) pretty funny. :o)

Comment: Instead of *use jQuery*, it can now be referred to as *use Micheal Jackson*.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring You say that, but *don't* want the MJ image... :P

Comment: it's true. it was amusing for sure. but what did it have to do with the answer? (yes, I get the mj/kids analogy).

Comment: @rockinthesixstring Well, let's see if it can survive *once* more. :D

Comment: @alex I wish I could up-vote your edit. Your comment will do, good sir.

Comment: looks like [Reigel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/251986/reigel) has a grudge, or a bone, or something.

Comment: I would vote to rollback if the image came *after* the answer

Comment: @rockin - I think Josh Stodola meant *after* in the sense of sequential order in the post, not chronological order.

Comment: Make it even simpler by changing `$(this).find('.goal-action')` to `$('.goal-action', this)`.

Comment: @shadowhand - that syntax is not recommended per resig, plus `.find` is just easily more readable.

Comment: @meder Do you have reference for that?

Comment: @shadowhand I'm pretty sure that context param (2nd argument) just gets translated to `find()` anyway.

Answer (score 14):

have you heard about [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) ?

```
$('.goal-small-container').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.goal-actions').css({visibility: "visible"});
}, function () {
  $(this).find('.goal-actions').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Comment: I had not! That is *exactly* what I was looking for. Also appreciate what I think was an edit.

Comment: ^_^ I was the first to answer, sadly, they got a higher votes. ;)

Comment: I did appreciate that you were first to answer, but seeing `.find()` used with the chain of inherited classes and the single class was also useful for someone unfamiliar.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of

```
$(this).children('.goal-content').children('.goal-row').children('.goal-actions').css({visibility: "visible"});
```

You can use:

```
$(this).find('> .goal-content > .goal-row > .goal-actions').css({visibility: "visible"});
```

For exactly the same meaning. If there's no chance of that being ambiguous, however, (`.goal-actions` will only appear in that structure of the markup) you can just use `find('.goal-actions')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
$('.goal-small-container').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('goal-actions').show();
}, function() {
   $(this).find('goal-actions').hide();
});
```

Comment: Dang. In the time it took me to write this on my iPhone, so many other answers came in!

Comment: Programming on the iPhone is a painful experience, IMO.

Comment: Actually, `.show()` and `.hide()` have been tested and *do not* have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use .show() and .hide() on the second `<div>`? And, initially have them display hidden or something.

Comment: `.show()` and `.hide()` have been tested and *do not* have the desired effect.