# I need a better jQuery selector to cut down on children() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Currently I am using
`$('table').children('tfoot').children('tr').children('td');`

to get the only td in the tfoot.

I dont like using `.children()` 3 times,

Is there a better way?

---

**Edit**
Slight correction
The selector is actually

```
var table = this;
$(table).children('tfoot').children('tr').children('td');
```

as this is inside a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('table > tfoot > tr > td')
```

[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) searches in immediate children, so to replicate this, I used the [direct descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) (`>`).

#### Update

From your update, you could do...

```
$(table).find(' > tfoot > tr > td')
```

or you could replace `table` with `this`.

I'm glad you are [thinking of the children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852260/jquery-but-what-about-all-the-children).

Comment: Cheers,

Please see my edit above, I tried `$(table).children('tfoot > tr > td');` But that did not work, any ideas?

Comment: @Hailwood That should work, as a `table` should only have one `tfoot` (i.e. not multiple and not nested). Can we see some HTML?

Comment: @Hailwood That's a long 5 minutes :P

Comment: @alex Does saying my clock stopped fix it ;)

Comment: Or even `$("tfoot > tr > td", table);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table>tfoot td');
```

You better to read about CSS-style selectors.

And for updated version:

```
$('tfoot>td',this);
```